Flutter: getNextFrame works in app but not in tests (issue compiling custom markers for Google Maps SDK)
I'm building my first Flutter app and I wanted to have some custom markers for the Google Maps SDK (as the default markers aren't great).
I wanted these custom markers to be generated programmatically so that I could easily change their colour in accordance with the app's current theme.
I was able to write this lovely function:
Future<BitmapDescriptor> getColoredMarker(String primaryType, Color color) async {
  late String assetPath;
  if (primaryType == "Food") {
    assetPath = "assets/foodMarker.png";
  }

  if (primaryType == "Shopping") {
    assetPath = "assets/shoppingMarker.png";
  }

  if (primaryType == "Music") {
    assetPath = "assets/musicMarker.png";
  }

  if (primaryType == "Event") {
    assetPath = "assets/eventsMarker.png";
  }

  if (primaryType == "Service") {
    assetPath = "assets/servicesMarker.png";
  }

  try {
    int markerPixelSize = 288;

    // Load the backdrop image (frame)
    final ByteData backdropData = await rootBundle.load("assets/markerIconFrame.png");
    final ui.Codec backdropCodec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
      backdropData.buffer.asUint8List(),
      targetWidth: markerPixelSize,
      targetHeight: markerPixelSize,
    );
    // The below line does not seem to work at all in the unit tests, it crashes the function without error
    final ui.FrameInfo backdropFrame = await backdropCodec.getNextFrame();
    final ui.Image backdropImage = backdropFrame.image;

    // Load the base image (to be colorized)
    final ByteData markerData = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
    final ui.Codec markerCodec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
      markerData.buffer.asUint8List(),
      targetWidth: markerPixelSize,
      targetHeight: markerPixelSize,
    );
    // The below line does not seem to work at all in the unit tests, it crashes the function without error
    final ui.FrameInfo markerFrame = await markerCodec.getNextFrame();
    final ui.Image markerImage = markerFrame.image;

    // Create a canvas to draw both images
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);

    // Draw the backdrop image without any color filter
    final Paint backdropPaint = Paint(); // No color filter
    canvas.drawImage(backdropImage, Offset.zero, backdropPaint);

    // Draw the marker image on top with the color overlay
    final Paint markerPaint = Paint()..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcIn); // Apply color to the marker image
    canvas.drawImage(markerImage, Offset.zero, markerPaint);

    // Convert the final image to a BitmapDescriptor
    final ui.Image finalImage = await recorder.endRecording().toImage(
          markerImage.width,
          markerImage.height,
        );
    final ByteData? byteData = await finalImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

    return BitmapDescriptor.bytes(pngBytes, imagePixelRatio: 1.0, height: 48.0, width: 48.0);
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Custom marker rendering failed: $e");
    return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
  }
}

It combines two PNGs and applied a colour overlay to one of them, which resulted in these lovely specimens in the picture below:
Screenshot of my custom map markers
All was going well until it came time to check my tests...
Although these markers render as expected in the app it seems that when it comes time to test them the markers are never added to the map because getNextFrame seems to crash (without logging an error).
I tried adding some error handling and logging, etc but it seems that when this function crashes it does so without error. Instead my parent function (getColoredMarker) just stops dead. This means the custom marker is never rendered and the marker is never added to the map.
I've ensured that my assets are definitely being loaded by the tests (they are) and also tried adding TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); to the test's setUp phase, but to no avail.
I've put some horrible workarounds in place for now but if any of you have any insight into why this might be occurring (and how I can fix it properly) I'd be interested to know.

Are you able to provide a sample app to demo so the community can see?
